# extensions.gnome.org "An unexpected error occurred" on Firefox (snap)

Tags: firefox, snap, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

When visiting https://extensions.gnome.org in Firefox (snap), I see this message displayed in the website itself:

[image: Screenshot: To control GNOME Shell extensions using this site you must install GNOME Shell integration that consists of two parts: browser extension and native host messaging application. Click here to install browser extension. See wiki page for native host connector installation instructions.]

I clicked the link to install the browser extension, and then I refreshed the page. Now I see this error in the web page itself:

[image: Screenshot]

The error says: "An unexpected error occurred".

How do I fix this?

I don't experience this error on Google Chrome installed using the `.deb` file. I'm using Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: Maybe a silly question: Did you try to restart Firefox?

Comment: Is package `chrome-gnome-shell` on your system?

Comment: @nobody Yes, it's installed.

Comment: According to [Gnome wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeShellIntegration/Installation?action=show&redirect=Projects%2FGnomeShellIntegrationForChrome%2FInstallation), for ubuntu 23.10, you should install `gnome-browser-connector` instead of `chrome-gnome-shell`